# How can I get rid of the `Node "13.0.0-nightly20190802452b393c1f"` so that I can be able to create a react app using the `create-react-app` tool?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, create-react-app, npm-scripts

I'm trying to create a react app using npx's `create-react-app` command in `ubuntu 18.04` terminal.
I have `Node v12.8.0` installed. When I run the command `npx create-react-app .` in the directory of my app, I expect the react app boilerplate folders and files to be generated since I have the latest version of `Node` `v12.8.0` and `npm` `v6.10.2` in my machine.Instead, I get the below output...

```
npx: installed 91 in 5.725s

Creating a new React app in /home/<my-PC>/Documents/todo-app.

warning You are using Node "13.0.0-nightly20190802452b393c1f" which is not supported and may encounter bugs or unexpected behavior. Yarn supports the following semver range: "^4.8.0 || ^5.7.0 || ^6.2.2 || >=8.0.0"
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.17.3
warning You are using Node "13.0.0-nightly20190802452b393c1f" which is not supported and may encounter bugs or unexpected behavior. Yarn supports the following semver range: "^4.8.0 || ^5.7.0 || ^6.2.2 || >=8.0.0"
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error @babel/core@7.5.5: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=6.9.0". Got "13.0.0-nightly20190802452b393c1f"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd /home/<my-PC>/Documents/todo-app has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting todo-app/ from /home/<my-PC>/Documents
Done.
```

So it ends up deleting the generated app folder as soon as it's created. I think it is being affected by the `Node "13.0.0-nightly20190802452b393c1f"` specified above.
I have tried to locate it but I can't find it on my machine.
On the terminal, when I run `node -v` I get the version `v12.8.0` which is for nodejs. Am stuck here...

Comment: Have you installed node 13 somewhere?

Comment: No. I only have node `v12.8.0`

Comment: What happens if you run it with `npx -p node@12 create-react-app todo-app` ?

Comment: @techxplorer__ how did you solve this issue, I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

1. Uninstall the node js from ubuntu software manager.
2. Then install node js with the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nodejs
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple versions of nodejs installed, you could target them directly with the `-p` option:

```
npx -p node@12
```

For create-react-app

```
npx -p node@12 create-react-app billion-dollar-project
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and forcing create-react-app to use npm instead of yarn fixed it. Try `npx create-react-app appname --use-npm`

Answer (score 0):

Simply run the following:

```
create-react-app app-name --use-npm
```

This explicitly tells react to use npm instead of yarn.