# When i try to do create-react-app gives different error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

When I try to start the app using

```
npx create-react-app projectname
```

it gives error :

```
error @babel/core@7.9.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=6.9.0". Got "15.0.0-nightly20200618a4f3206b76"
error Found incompatible module.
```

The complete msg:

```
warning You are using Node "15.0.0-nightly20200618a4f3206b76" which is not supported and may encounter bugs or unexpected behavior. Yarn supports the following semver range: "^4.8.0 || ^5.7.0 || ^6.2.2 || >=8.0.0"
(node:159119) [DEP0139] DeprecationWarning: Calling process.umask() with no arguments is prone to race conditions and is a potential security vulnerability.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.4
warning You are using Node "15.0.0-nightly20200618a4f3206b76" which is not supported and may encounter bugs or unexpected behavior. Yarn supports the following semver range: "^4.8.0 || ^5.7.0 || ^6.2.2 || >=8.0.0"
(node:159152) [DEP0139] DeprecationWarning: Calling process.umask() with no arguments is prone to race conditions and is a potential security vulnerability.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error @babel/core@7.9.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=6.9.0". Got "15.0.0-nightly20200618a4f3206b76"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd /home/rudeprabesh/work/hellow has failed.
```

> create-react-app version is: v3.4.1
>
> node version is: v12.18.2
>
> npm version is: v6.14.5
>
> npx version is: v6.14.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall the node js from ubuntu software manager.

Then install node js with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

from : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57532708/10264127)

I was successful with that step

Comment: Thanks, man, but I also did same, I forgot to close the question.